# ssmtp cuts the email i'm sending

Tags: bash, ssmtp

so here's the whole text i'm sending:

[image]

and here's the email i'm receiving:

[image]

basically i just *cat* the file and echo then pipe it to ssmtp like this:

```
result=`cat file.out` 
echo "$result" | ssmtp $emailaddr
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example basically, add an empty line in front of all lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssmtp protocol defines the lines in format `something: something` to be the header lines, like `From: some@email.com` defines where from the email is. So if you want to specify the body only, add a leading empty line as the separator between the header and body of the message and hopefully `ssmtp` should pick it up.